# Proving that $\sin(nt)$ and $\cos(nt)$, for integer $n$, can be expressed as polynomials in $\sin t$ and $\cos t$

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

> How can I prove that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exist polynomials $p_n(x,y)$ and $q_n(x,y)$ in two variables $x,y$ with real coefficients such that:
>   $$\sin(nt) = p_n(\sin(t),\cos(t))\quad\text{and}\quad \cos(nt) = q_n(\sin (t), \cos(t))$$
>   for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, using the Addition Theorem for $\sin$ and $\cos$?

Edit of my thoughts:
I know that this is obvious for n=1 but I'm not sure if I can use induction or rather how I can combine that with the Theorem. One of the answers already statet that I can indeed use induction so I will continue to try it that way.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community here prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker knows about a problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already know or talking over your head. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.) Since comments are easily overlooked, [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3479788/edit) to add your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $\sin(a+t)=\sin(a)\cos(t)+\sin(t)\cos(a)$, and a similar formula for $\cos(a+b)$.  Using this identity, we can prove the claim by induction on $n$, as follows.

When $n=1$, this is clear.
If you assume this claim holds for both $\sin$ and $\cos$ for $n=m-1$, then you use the formula above with $a=(m-1)t$, to see that $\sin(mt)=\sin((m-1)t)\cos(t)+\sin(t)\cos((m-1)t)$.  Since by induction $\sin((m-1)t)$ is a polynomial function in $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$, then $\sin(mt)$ is a polynomial function.  The same is true for $\cos(mt)$.  Therefore, the claim holds for $n=m$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula): $$(\cos(t)+i\sin(t))^n=\cos(nt)+i\sin(nt)$$

Answer (score 1):

You can both prove it and compute the polynomials by using [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) and the [Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).

The first tells you that $$\cos(nt)+i\sin(nt)=(\cos(t)+i\sin(t))^n$$

The second tells you that $$(A+B)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}A^kB^{n-k}$$

Therefore $$\cos(nt)+i\sin(tn)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}i^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}\cos^k(t)\sin^{n-k}(t)$$

Take into account that the powers of $i$ are $i^0=1, i^1=i, i^2=-1, i^3=-i$ and these values repeat periodically. So,

$$\cos(nt)=\sum_{k=0,\text{ even}}^{n}(-1)^{k/2}\binom{n}{k}\cos^k(t)\sin^{n-k}(t)$$

$$\sin(nt)=\sum_{k=0,\text{ odd}}^{n}(-1)^{(k-1)/2}\binom{n}{k}\cos^{n-k}(t)\sin^{k}(t)$$

Answer (score 0):

Define a recursive function $S_n(t)=\sin nt=\sin(n-1)t\cos t+\cos(n-1)t\sin t$ and $C_n(t)=\cos nt=\cos(n-1)t\cos t-\sin t\sin (n-1)t$

Therefore, $S_n(t)=S_{n-1}(t)\cos t+C_{n-1}(t)\sin t \text{ and }C_n(t)=C_{n-1}(t)\cos t-S_{n-1}(t)\sin t$.

By induction,you can easily prove that the functions $S_n(t), C_n(t)$ are polynomials in $\sin t, \cos t$